# How to display private properties of a class (PHP OOP)

Tags: php, oop

I've read that it's better to have properties of a class be private, and use get/set methods to access/change them.

So I set up a class that way, but I want to be able to display the properties in an html table and I was going to use a separate htmlTable display class to do it.

I thought of 4 possibilities. Feel free to skip them if you already know the ideal way to do this.

Thank you.

Possibilities:

1. I can get the class fields using:

   ```
   $class_Vars = get_class_vars($object_class);
   $fields = $class_vars['fields'];

   // But as far as iterating through each object, this doesn't work:

   foreach($object_array as $current_object) {
       foreach($current_object as $value) {
           $html = '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
       }
   }
   ```

   The values are private and inaccessible.
2. A possible solution that looks very clumsy and would probably be a debugging nightmare is:

   ```
   foreach($fields as $value) {
       $get_func = 'get' . ucwords($value); // e.g. $get_func = 'getId'
       $current_value = $current_object->$get_func();
   }
   ```

   I think it would work but it doesn't sit right with me.
3. Interface.
   Another possibility is to write in an htmlTable function into every class I want to do it. But that is a lot of code reuse.
4. Interface.
   Or I could write in an `export()` function into every class that just outputs an array with property names and values. Then my htmlTable class can just handle those outputs.

Comment: PHP's reflection might help. http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflection.extending.php

Comment: actually i would say that it is better to set variables as `protected`, then the classes, which inherit from the original, can access them too.

Comment: @tereško That depends on whether the classes that inherit should have access. Be wary of inheritance - it's one of the most over-used OOP features. But if you do plan for inheritance make sure your original class is "Open to extension but not to modification". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle

Comment: @liquorvicar , i wouldn't have known .. =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make them public or make `get`/`set` methods.

You could also make a `getAll()` method that returns an associative array with all of your private variables.

Comment: The problem with get/set methods is coding for the function names, which will be different for each property.
I just tried the getAll() method (which I mentioned in my question as "export()") and it does work.
Also, annoyingly, in Dreamweaver this is flagged as an error even though it's not: "$fields = $object_class_name::$fields"

Comment: You could just write the __get($name) { return $this->$name; } magic method.